# Posting Image to Facebook using Ajax: Authorization Dialog not working

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post image to facebook with PHP SDK using ajax,(its my 1st attempt with ajax upload) but when user clicks button, FB App. authorize dialog not appears if user already authorized the app & logged in then Image post success: here is my code:

### view.php?id=xxxx

```
    document.getElementById("uploadfb").onclick=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    //id hidden input type in a form
        id = $("#id").val();    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "uploadfb.php",
            data: {id: id},
            dataType : 'json',
            forceIframeTransport: true, //force use iframe or will no work
            autoUpload : true,              
            success: function(result){
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    return false;
    };
```

### uploadfb.php contains all necessary fb login code & image posting

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
require_once 'config.php';
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if($user)
        {
        // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
            }
        } else {
            $params = array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos'
            );
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
            header('location:' .$loginUrl);
        }
///// then image post code
if($user)
    {
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($id);
    $post = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
    }
```

When a User already Authorized App. click upload button image uploads to facebook & returns success.
Problem arise when new user click then facebook application authorization dialog not appear it returns Error

also tried changing redirect uri in getLoginUrl params to uploadfb.php?id=xxxxx
but still application authorization not appearing.

for Testing purpose I placed a separate button "Login with facebook" with only Login Code

### login.php

```
require_once 'config.php';
$user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user)
    {
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
        $user = null;
        }
    } else {
        $params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos'
        );
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        header('location:' .$loginUrl);
    }
```

I came to conclusion that Auth. Dialog not appearing in ajax request.
Now when a user 1st Login with Login button then click Upload button Result is success 
Image post successfully. 
But if New User directly(without 1st authorization), click Upload button it gives Error.

I dnt want to place two separate buttons so User 1st click login and then upload button.
want when user click Upload button, if user not already auth. my application Authorization Dialogue window opens, which is not working here.

Something is missing in Ajax Code ? or its not possible to display auth. dialog in ajax request. Any alternative solution for this will be helpful too. Thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the JavaScript Login method to see if your Ajax call works, instead of using the PHP login method:

```
document.getElementById("uploadfb").onclick=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // id hidden input type in a form
    id = $("#id").val();
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "uploadfb.php",
          data: {id: id},
          dataType : 'json',
          forceIframeTransport: true, //force use iframe or will no work
          autoUpload : true,              
          success: function(result){
            alert("Success");
          },
          error: function(errorThrown){
            alert("Error");
          }
        });
      });
      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
```

I've basically wrapped the Ajax call with the FB.login() method, so the user is asked to login first, and then the Ajax call is made to upload the file. It should work for both logged and non-logged in users now.